# How to access or save the image generated by gradio_client on python

Tags: python, gradio

```py
from gradio_client import Client
    
client = Client("ByteDance/SDXL-Lightning")
result = client.predict(
        "astronaut riding a horse realistic",   
        "8-Step",   
        api_name="/generate_image"
)
print(result)
```

This is my code, it returns me a path in the form of string, so I can't do anything with it:

```
/tmp/gradio/ecfea853d51fb542f45865d58816480210e58ea3/image.png
```

How do I display it or save it?

I tried giving `download_files = True` in Client parameters but didn't see a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Pls use matplotlib and PIL:

```
image = Image.open(result)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.axis('off')  
plt.show()
image.save("output_image.png")
```

**Sample code:**

```
from gradio_client import Client
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

client = Client("ByteDance/SDXL-Lightning")
result = client.predict(
        "astronaut riding a horse realistic",   
        "8-Step",   
        api_name="/generate_image"
)

image = Image.open(result)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.axis('off')  
plt.show()
image.save("output_image.png")
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This works real good, I at first thought it just returns a string and couldn't do anything with it, but its perfect, thank you so much, appreciate a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think is eassier if u use this skimage

```
from gradio_client import Client

#Package for image display
from skimage import io

#Package for save the image
import os

client = Client("ByteDance/SDXL-Lightning")
result = client.predict(
        "astronaut riding a horse realistic",   
        "8-Step",   
        api_name="/generate_image"
)

#Move image from temporal place to desired destination
new_path = "./image.png"
os.replace(result, new_path)

#Show the image
img = io.imread(new_path)
io.imshow(img)
io.show()
```